# Pickle : using both __getstate__ and __getnewargs__

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I use pickle on python 2.7. I'm trying to call both methods `__getstate__` and `__getnewargs__` which I overrode.  I can't pickle attribute `c` because it's a instance of classe `D`.

```
 nn = C(7, 2)
 nn.d = 1
 pickle.dump(nn, open('c_save.p', 'wb'))
 nn2 = pickle.load(open('c_save.p', 'rb'))
 print nn2.__dict__
```

Returns :

```
getstate was called
setstate was called
{'a': 7, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
```

I see no calls of `__getnewargs__` which sould have created attribute `c`.

My code :

```
import pickle

class D(object):
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = D(a, b)
        self.d = 0

    def __getstate__(self):
        print 'getstate was called'
        odict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del odict['c']
        return odict

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        print 'getnewargs was called'
        return (self.b,self.a)

    def __setstate__(self, dict):
        print 'setstate was called'
        self.__dict__.update(dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__):

> New-style types can provide a **getnewargs**() method that is used for
>   protocol 2.

And for [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

> If the protocol parameter is omitted, protocol 0 is used.

Therefore, you'll have to explicitly set the pickle protocol to 2 like so:

```
pickle.dump(nn, open('c_save.p', 'wb'), protocol=2)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfectly. It returns as expected
    `getnewargs was called`
    `getstate was called`
    `setstate was called`
    `{'a': 7, 'c': <__main__.D object at 0x7fd1bd8c1710>, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}`